# Is it possible to store widgets in a list/array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, list

All- I have a ton of Spinners that I would like to store in a list/array so that I don't have to rewrite lots of code. I have about 30 spinners that go through the same exact code. I am trying to figure out a way to put 30 spinners in an array list and then run the array/list through my code. Example:

```
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
List<String> listOfSpinners= new ArrayList(); // This is the part I am not sure about                       
    listOfSpinners.add(spinner1);
    listOfSpinners.add(spinner2); 


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSpinner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.spinnerlayout, infoInSpinner);


    adapterSpinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);  
    listOfSpinners.setAdapter(adapterSpinner); //I want to use the list here (listOfSpinners)
```

I don't even know if this is possible but I though I ask otherwise it is going to be a long night of writing repeating code:). Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the IDs in an array, as `int`s. Then loop through them to set the adapter.

```
ArrayList<Integer> listOfSpinners = new ArrayList<Integer>();
listOfSpinners.add(R.id.spinner);
listOfSpinners.add(R.id.spinner2); 

ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSpinner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.spinnerlayout, infoInSpinner);

adapterSpinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
for (Integer spinner : listOfSpinners) {
    // If you want multiple adapters, move the adapter code in here and alter it accordingly.
    ((Spinner) findViewById(spinner)).setAdapter(adapterSpinner);
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should work just fine! Keep in mind, this sets all `Spinner`s to have the same adapter.

Comment: I will try it please hold on.

Comment: Weird, I get the first spinner but not any following, any ideas? Meanwhile I will try again.

Comment: Never mind. I got it, thanks a billion for your help! Saved me from a dreary task!

Comment: Glad you got it--do I need to edit anything in my code above to reflect the change?